# How to open Go2Shell preferences in Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, iterm2

I'm trying to change my default Go2Shell terminal to iTerm2.

I've read that Go2Shell preferences are only accessible from the command line, but I'm struggling to find what command actually needs to be run to open them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think it's this one:

```
open -a Go2Shell --args config
```

That will open the configuration screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to [this program](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/go2shell/id445770608?mt=12): It's right there in the description...

[image]